# Не работает проверка действий

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Внизу есть часть, которая в ответе за выбор действия. При вводе действия с начало идет первое(updates), а потом второй. Хотя я вводил команду для второго действия

```
import pyttsx3
    speak_engine = pyttsx3.init()

    def Calculator():
        summ = 0
        razn = 0
        umn = 1
        print('Какое действие вы хотите выполнить?(-,+,x,:) или вы можете написать help')

        deist = input()
        if deist == 'help':
            print('x - умножение; : - деление ')
            print('Пожалуй продолжим. Введите действие.')
            deist = input()
        if deist == "+" :
            speak('Сколько чисел?')
            kol = int(input())
            for i in range(kol):
                print('Введите числа: ')
                num = int(input())
                summ = num + summ
            speak('Ваш ответ: '+ str(summ))

        if deist == "-" :
            print('Введите 2 числа: ')
            num1 = int(input())
            num2 = int(input())
            print('Ваш ответ: '+ str(num1-num2))

        if deist == "x" :
            print('Введите 2 числа: ')
            num1 = int(input())
            num2 = int(input())
            speak('Ваш ответ: '+ str(num1*num2))
        if deist == "/" :
            print('Введите 2 числа: ')
            num1 = int(input())
            num2 = int(input())
            speak('Ваш ответ: '+ str(num1/num2))
        speak('Спасиба за пользование Шайны(v0.01)! Ждите ближайшие обновления!')

    def speak(what):
        print( what )
        speak_engine.say( what )
        speak_engine.runAndWait()
        speak_engine.stop()

    speak('Здравствуйте, я Шайна! Я машина пока-что способный только на вычисление')
    print('Выберите следующее действие: Calculator(калькулятор), updates(обновления)')
    funct = input()

    if funct == 'updates' or 'обновления':
        speak('Вы выбрали описание обновления!')
        print('Список пока пуст')
    elif funct == 'calculator' or 'калькулятор' or 'n' or 'rfkmrekznjh' or 'сфдсгдфещк':
        speak('Вы выбрали калькулятор')
        Calculator()
```

Comment: У Вас довольно интересный перевод. А остальные  функции калькулятора работают ? Интересует больше всего 'help' .

Comment: Да, все работает. А что такое? Я новенький во все этом деле.

Comment: Все были новенькими. А смущал именно способ проверки строчніх значений на истинность. Но уже nomnoms12 Вам написал даже полное руководство.

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно сравниваете команду со строками.

Ваши условия:

```py
if funct == 'updates' or 'обновления':
    ...
elif funct == 'calculator' or 'калькулятор' or 'n' or 'rfkmrekznjh' or 'сфдсгдфещк':
    ...
```

будут всегда истинны, следовательно и исполняться будет всегда 1-ый блок.

В Вашем коде значение переменной `funct` сравнивается со строкой `'updates'`, после чего результат сравнивается с логическим типом, в который преобразовывается строка `'обновления'`, то есть с `True`, таким образом всегда приводя к истине.

Первое Ваше условие эквивалентно следующему:

```py
if funct == 'updates' or True:  # if True:
    ...
```

---

Для сравнения переменной с несколькими строками, Вам следует делать так:

```py
if funct == 'updates' or funct == 'обновления':
    ...
```

или так:

```py
if funct in ['updates', 'обновления']:
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли